# NSMutableArray losing all objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

My NSMutableArray is losing all its data that I am adding from a Facebook search. I have followed the loop through each iteration an the loop runs correctly and adds all the data, but once this code is executed, my `NSMutableArrays` revert to having zero objects. Could it have something to do that all the adding is happening within the request connection? The Arrays are decalred and initialised outside of it though, so I don't understand why it would be the problem. Any help appreciated!

in my ViewDidLoad

```
_namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"search?q=food&type=place&center=51.89,-8.472&distance=1000" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"user events: %@", result]);
        NSArray *test = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (FBGraphObject *obj in test) {
            if ([obj objectForKey:@"category"]){
                [_namesArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"category"]];
            }
            if ([obj objectForKey:@"name"]){
                [_categoryArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"name"]];
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"error %@", error.description]);
    }

}];
```

header file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *namesArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;
```

Comment: Where in this are you testing the arrays?

Comment: In the end I want to use one of the array counts to set the size of a `UITableViewController`, but if I set a breakpoint directly after the code above in my `ViewDidLoad`, my arrays are empty

Comment: That thing is not a basic block, it's an Objective-C block.  The code inside of it is not executed sequentially like everything else around it, it's executed when the request to facebook's graph API completes.  Try logging *in* the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays get filled with elements within `completionHandler` which is executed asynchronously. It seems like the reason of your issue is that you try to access the arrays out of `completionHandler`. Actually you should work with arrays within `completionHandler` or start another method from this block.

```
_namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// 1 - Start request
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"search?q=food&type=place&center=51.89,-8.472&distance=1000" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // 3 - request is finished. Fill the arrays

    if (!error) {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"user events: %@", result]);
        NSArray *test = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (FBGraphObject *obj in test) {
            if ([obj objectForKey:@"category"]){
                [_namesArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"category"]];
            }
            if ([obj objectForKey:@"name"]){
                [_categoryArray addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"name"]];
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"error %@", error.description]);
    }

    // Use arrays. For example, reload UITableView
    [_tableView reloadData];

}];

// 2 - now request is not finished yet
```

Comment: reloading the table view worked perfectly! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are misunderstanding the flow of execution

```
//Point 1. ode executed first
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"search?q=food&type=place&center=51.89,-8.472&distance=1000"
  completionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
  {
    //Point 3. Code executed last, once the network request is finished.
  }
//Point 2. Code executed second
```

If you check your arrays at point 2, they won't be populated yet. The arrays won't be populated until after the completion handler fires, some time later.